# Set mouse position in C# and .Net Core

Tags: c#, linux, windows, .net-core, mouse

I'm trying to set the mouse cursor position from a console .NET Core application that will run both on Windows and Linux. Is there any API that will let me set the position on both OSs?

Comment: Linux doesn't work well with setting mouse positions due to the drivers AFAIK

Comment: I'd say it's unlikely. You're probably going to need to determine which platform you're on and call the appropriate system function with PInvoke. And with Linux I suspect the call will be different depending on which GUI is being used...

Comment: I figured as much, is there any X11 function that does it?

Answer (score 1):

Getting mouse cursor position on Windows with .NET Core is possible with `GetCursorPos` in `user32.dll`.

See this example:

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool GetCursorPos(out Point lpPoint);

    private static void Main()
    {
        Point mouse = default;
        if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
        {
            GetCursorPos(out mouse);
        }
        else
        {
            // How to do on Linux and OSX?
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Mouse X:{mouse.X} Y:{mouse.Y}");
    }
}
```

If you want to download this sample project to test feel free: https://github.com/sergiocabral/Sample.CSharpNETCore.GetCursorPosition

Comment: Original question wanted Linux...?